# Sitemap Successfully Crawled and Discovered all 90K pages, yet Google Search results empty

Tags: google-search, googlebot, sitemap, xml-sitemap, sitemap-index

I have my website running on Spring Boot and have created `sitemap.xml` for `google indexing`. When logged into the google console I could see all 90K pages are discovered and success as the status. It is in `XML` format.

Yet I`m unable to see the records in the google search.

[image]

Pls advise.

Thank you.